# Does SAP Business Objects 4.1 version support Snowflake cloud database?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, business-objects

We are upgrading database from Teradata to Snowflake cloud database. We have SAP Business Objects BI Platform 4.1 Support Pack 8 Patch 3 Version: 14.1.8.2168. Is this version of SAP BO compatible with snowflake or we must upgrade to SAP BO 4.2 ? Upgrading is not part of our original plan, hence need definite answers so that I can tell the same to client

Answer (score 1):

According to this blogpost (https://blogs.sap.com/2020/03/12/snowflake-for-sap-businessobjects-4.2-sp08/) only SAP BI 4.2 SP8 or above is able to connect to Snowflake with a Snowflake specific driver.

But you can still try to use JDBC: https://blogs.sap.com/2018/11/20/how-to-set-up-sap-businessobjects-with-snowflake-using-jdbc/

Comment: You can also use Generic ODBC for BI4.1.